# How to create xamarin forms button left corner radius

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a way to create a custom renderer for a button in xamarin forms, so that I can get rounded corners on the left side of the button. I have tried searching for a solution, but without any luck.

Comment: Go easy on the down votes, there are no tutorials or anything about this topic of a button rounded on one side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android you can use [`shape`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource?#Shape) in your `drawable` folder, named `layout_bg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

In your custom render:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control != null) {
        Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.layout_bg);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a very popular open source project [FlexButton](https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/flexbutton) which can help solving the challenge you are facing. If for some reason you would still like to solve it yourself, without introducing external dependencies, then you can check the source code of this project to get a better idea on how it can be achieved.

Alternative option is to search the web more precisely and check threads like [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63148/xamarin-forms-button-with-only-single-border-on-bottom).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For making different corner radius for button or any control.You need declare top left, top right ,bottom left bottom right corner radius in float[] array varaible and pass the float variable in SetCornerRadii() Method of GradientDrawable.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
{

  base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetAllCaps(false);
            GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();                
            float[] radius= new float[8];
            radius[0] = 46f;   //Top Left corner
            radius[1] = 46f;   //Top Left corner
            radius[2] = 0;     //Top Right corner
            radius[3] = 0;     //Top Right corner
            radius[4] = 0;     //Bottom Right corner
            radius[5] = 0;     //Bottom Right corner
            radius[6] = 46f;   //Bottom Left corner
            radius[7] = 46f;   //Bottom Left corner
            gradientDrawable.SetCornerRadii(radius);
            Control.SetBackground(gradientDrawable);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN25E.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Color background = Color.ParseColor("#ff3c4550");
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.SetCornerRadius(10);
shape.SetColor(background.ToArgb());
Background = shape;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Does `SetCornerRadius` affect only the specific corners requested?

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry for beeing super short but I run out of time before my vacation ;) Anyhow I hope it helped the one or other devs. `(SetCornerRadius)` is applied to all corners. Use this code in the XF android custom renderer code within the `OnElementChanged` method and it should word. I use it on my own within a own created button derived from the Android.Widget.Button.